# How to I get Ruby Async gem versions 1.xx to run tasks in in parallel?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use the [Async](https://rubygems.org/gems/async) gem with ruby 2.7 which only supports the 1.xx versions.  I installed the latest 1.xx version (1.31.0).

When I run the following simple example from the [documentation](https://socketry.github.io/async/guides/asynchronous-tasks/index.html) it should run all 3 subtasks in parallel and finish in 1 second,  however it seems to run them sequentially and finishes in 3 seconds.

If I run the same example using ruby 3.1 and the latest Async gem version (2.6.1), it does seem to run them in parallel and finishes in 1 second.

My initial thought was that there is a bug in the gem, so I uninstalled the gem and installed several back level versions and they all behave the same way, which makes me think I am misunderstanding something with the 1.xx versions.

```
require "async"

Async do
  3.times do |i|
    Async do
      sleep 1
      puts "Hello World #{i}"
    end
  end
end
```

### Update

using task.sleep does allow all sleeps to happen in parallel,  but it seems like it may be a special case (special version of sleep is called)?

```
Async do |task|
  3.times do |i|
    Async do
      start = Time.now
      puts "starting task #{i} at #{start.to_f}"
      (0..1000000/((i+1)*10000)).reduce(:*)
      done = Time.now
      puts "finished task #{i} at #{done.to_f},  took #{done - start}"
    end
  end
end
```

A slightly more real world example again shows serial execution.

```
starting task 0 at 1686603935.7939696
finished task 0 at 1686603935.7940578,  took 8.799e-05
starting task 1 at 1686603935.7941055
finished task 1 at 1686603935.7941372,  took 3.1856e-05
starting task 2 at 1686603935.7941997
finished task 2 at 1686603935.7942228,  took 2.3047e-05
```

I have not tried this on ruby 3.1 with the 2.xx version of the gem yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience using the `async` gem with Ruby 2.7.5. In your original code, the tasks would run concurrently if you make requests to a slow web server, for example.

```
require 'async'
require 'open-uri'

uri = 'https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/5'
puts "Start: #{Time.now}"

Async do
  3.times do |i|
    Async do
      puts "Before Request #{i} - #{Time.now}"
      URI.open uri
      puts "After Request #{i} - #{Time.now}"
    end
  end
end

puts "End: #{Time.now}"
```

When you run the code above, it will produce the following result:

```
Start: 2023-06-13 07:07:22 +0700
Before Request 0 - 2023-06-13 07:07:22 +0700
Before Request 1 - 2023-06-13 07:07:22 +0700
Before Request 2 - 2023-06-13 07:07:22 +0700
After Request 1 - 2023-06-13 07:07:28 +0700
After Request 0 - 2023-06-13 07:07:28 +0700
After Request 2 - 2023-06-13 07:07:33 +0700
End: 2023-06-13 07:07:33 +0700
```

In your `sleep` case, you should replace `sleep` with `task.sleep`.

```
require 'async'

puts "Start: #{Time.now}"

Async do
  3.times do |i|
    Async do |task|
      task.sleep 5
      puts "Hello World #{i} - #{Time.now}"
    end
  end
end

puts "End: #{Time.now}"
```

When you run the code above, it will produce the following result:

```
Start: 2023-06-12 20:38:24 +0700
Hello World 0 - 2023-06-12 20:38:29 +0700
Hello World 1 - 2023-06-12 20:38:29 +0700
Hello World 2 - 2023-06-12 20:38:29 +0700
End: 2023-06-12 20:38:29 +0700
```

##### Parallel Gem

As an alternative, you can achieve the same purpose by using the `parallel` gem.

```
require 'parallel'
require 'open-uri'

uris = ['https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/5', 'https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/3', 'https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/1']
puts "Start: #{Time.now}"

results = Parallel.map(uris, in_threads: 3) do |uri|
  puts "Before Request #{uri} - #{Time.now}"
  URI.open uri
  puts "After Request #{uri} - #{Time.now}"
end

puts "End: #{Time.now}"
```

Result:

```
Start: 2023-06-13 07:25:12 +0700
Before Request https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/5 - 2023-06-13 07:25:12 +0700
Before Request https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/3 - 2023-06-13 07:25:12 +0700
Before Request https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/1 - 2023-06-13 07:25:12 +0700
After Request https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/3 - 2023-06-13 07:25:16 +0700
After Request https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/1 - 2023-06-13 07:25:16 +0700
After Request https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/delay/5 - 2023-06-13 07:25:17 +0700
End: 2023-06-13 07:25:17 +0700
```

Comment: Thanks that does make all 3 run in parallel but it seems to do so by calling a version of sleep define on the Reactor class,  if I traced it correctly. I am wondering if I replaced task.sleep with something that truly takes a long time if it would run them in parallel or not

Comment: Yes, it would run them in parallel. I've updated my answer.

Comment: respectfully,  that is a different gem. I did upvote your answer because it provided useful information,  but I would like to learn what, if anything I am misunderstanding  concerning the async gem.